# Unprecise p-values in Stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer

I want the same stars for significancies in regression output in stargazer as in the "normal output".

I produce data

```
library("stargazer"); library("lmtest"); library("sandwich")
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(y=1001:1100)
df$x <- c(1:70,-100:-71) + rnorm(100, 0, 74.8)
model <- lm(log(y) ~ x, data=df)
```

and get some model estimates where the coefficient on x has a p-value of 0.1023

```
coeftest(model, vcov = vcovHC(model, type="HC3"))
```

I want to have these results in LaTeX. Based on the same function I calculate heteroscedasticity consistent standard estimates and let stargazer use them.

```
stderr_HC3_model <- sqrt(diag(vcovHC(model, type = "HC3")))
stargazer(model, se=list(stderr_HC3_model))
```

The stargazer output has a star at the coefficient indicating significance when alpha=10%. I want stargazer to give the same as the coeftest. (Because of the comparability with Stata where reg L_y x, vce(hc3) gives exactly the coeftest results.)

I played around with the stargazer options p.auto, t.auto which did not help. When I execute "stargazer" I cannot view the underlying code as it is possible in other cases. What to do?

---

Richards answer helped me. I indicate the steps I used to give out more than one regression (let's say ols_a and ols_b).

```
ses <- list(coeftest(ols_a, vcov = vcovHC(ols_a, type="HC3"))[,2],
        coeftest(ols_b, vcov = vcovHC(ols_b, type="HC3"))[,2])
pvals <- list(coeftest(ols_a, vcov = vcovHC(ols_a, type="HC3"))[,4],
          coeftest(ols_b, vcov = vcovHC(ols_b, type="HC3"))[,4])
stargazer(ols_a, ols_b, type="text", p=pvals, se=ses)
```

Comment: to get the source code, try `stargazer:::.stargazer.wrap`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide the p values associated with your `coeftest`. From the man page.

> p a list of numeric vectors that will replace the default p-values for
>   each model. Matched by element names. These will form the basis of
>   decisions about significance stars

The following should work.

```
test <- coeftest(model, vcov = vcovHC(model, type="HC3"))
ses <- test[, 2]
pvals <- test[, 4]
stargazer(model, type="text", p=pvals, se=ses)
```

This provides the following.

```
===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                              log(y)           
-----------------------------------------------
x                            -0.00005          


Constant                     6.956***          
                              (0.003)          

-----------------------------------------------
Observations                    100            
R2                             0.026           
Adjusted R2                    0.016           
Residual Std. Error       0.027 (df = 98)      
F Statistic             2.620 (df = 1; 98)     
===============================================
Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be a minor issue but Richard's answer is actually not entirely correct -
 his stargazer output does not report any standard errors nor potential significance stars for the variable `x`.

Also when reporting only a single model in stargazer manual `coefficients`, `se`, `p` and `t` values have to be provided in a list. Otherwise stargazer will report an empty list.

The (slightly) corrected example:

```
test <- coeftest(model, vcov = vcovHC(model, type="HC3"))
ses <- list(test[, 2])
pvals <- list(test[, 4])
stargazer(model, type="text", p=pvals, se=ses)
```

Output:

```
=======================================================================
                                         Dependent variable:           
                              -----------------------------------------
                                        Daily added investors          
                                              negative                 
                                              binomial                 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
log(lag_raised_amount + 1)                    -0.466***                
                                               (0.124)                 

lag_target1                                   -0.661***                
                                               (0.134)                 

Constant                                      -3.480**                 
                                               (1.290)                 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                                    6,513                  
Log Likelihood                                 -8,834                
theta                                     1.840*** (0.081)             
Akaike Inf. Crit.                              17,924                
=======================================================================
Note:                         + p<0.1; * p<0.05; ** p<0.01; *** p<0.001
```

Answer (score 2):

There are inherent dangers associated with the `se` argument.

When using this approach, the user should be cautious wrt the arguments `t.auto` and `p.auto`, both of which default to `TRUE`. I think it would be cautious to set them both to `FALSE`, and supply manually `t` and `p` values.

Failure to do so, and you risk getting significance stars not in sync with the displayed p-values. (I suspect that stargazer will simply reuse the `se`, which are now different from the default ones, and recompute the displayed stars using this input; which will naturally yield unexpected results.)

See also:

- [Displaying p-values instead of SEs in parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542583/stargazer-in-r-changing-input-to-values-listed-in-parenthesis#comment45397240_24545556)