# How to change significance levels in Stargazer?

Tags: r, stargazer

### Problem

Stargazer shows significance levels of ∗ p<0.1; ∗∗ p<0.05; ∗∗∗ p<0.01
However, I would like to have significance levels of *p < 0.05, **p < 0.01, ***p <0.001

### What I found

In the [stargazer documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stargazer/versions/5.2.2/topics/stargazer) it is shown how to edit the notes section. But I would also like the stars in the table to correspond to that change.

### MWE

Don't know if one is necessary, but I stole this from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23217681/9427952) question, since it is rather close to my actual code.

```
library("stargazer"); library("lmtest"); library("sandwich")

set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(y=1001:1100)
df$x <- c(1:70,-100:-71) + rnorm(100, 0, 74.8)
model <- lm(log(y) ~ x, data=df)

test <- coeftest(model, vcov = vcovHC(model, type="HC3"))
ses <- test[, 2]
pvals <- test[, 4]
stargazer(model, type="text", p=pvals, se=ses)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searching, I found the answer in this R [cheatsheet](https://github.com/JakeRuss/cheatsheets/blob/master/stargazer.Rmd).

> #### Change the cutoffs for significance
>
> Notice that temperature, quarter3, and quarter4 have each lost a gold
> star  because we made it tougher to earn them.
>
> ````
> stargazer(output, output2, type = "html", 
>           star.cutoffs = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001)) # star.cutoffs = NULL by default ```
> ````

Now that I understood what it does, I realized that the answer was in the Stargazer [manual](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stargazer/versions/5.2.2/topics/stargazer) all along:

> **star.cutoffs**
>
> a numeric vector that indicates the statistical signficance cutoffs
> for the statistical significance 'stars.' For elements with NA values,
> the corresponding 'star' will not be used.

So the answer was trivial after all, just change the last line in the MWE to this:

```
stargazer(model, type="text", p=pvals, se=ses, c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001))
```